# Изменение высоты элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что установилось - высота документа или высота окна?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var visual = document.getElementById('text');
  visual.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="text" style="width: 50px">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Если на Ваш вопрос был дан ответ - выберите его как лучший. Для этого нажмите галочку под рейтингом необходимого ответа

Answer (score 2):

Данный код устанавливает высоту `height` элементу `text` так, что, своей высотой, элемент `text` занимает всю видимую часть страницы.

Все браузеры, кроме `IE8-`, поддерживают свойства `window.innerWidth/innerHeight`. Они хранят текущий размер окна браузера, то бишь размер видимой части сайта на нашем экране.

**UPD: внесена конкретика:**

Высота документа: `document.body.offsetHeight`.

Высота видимого окна(видимой части страницы): `window.innerHeight`.

Высота окна всего браузера(размер формы "Браузер"): `window.outerHeight`.

Comment: так высота документа или окна? вариантов ответа только два)

Comment: @KvinT, не высота окна, не высота документа, а высота элемента с идом `text`

Comment: нет такого ответа в задании) я сам понимаю, что элементу устанавливает) только документу или окну нужно ответить)

Comment: @KvinT, высота окна, которое видит юзер

Comment: @KvinT, Документ - вся страница от корки до корки. А окно - только область этого документа. В Вашем случае, думаю, окно.

Answer (score 1):

Высота окна - window.outerHeight

Comment: Только при чём тут она? Такая высота никому не нужна...

Comment: @qwertiy, не понял вашего вопроса... разве не очевидно что, если outerHeight - высота окна, то innerHeight - не его высота?.. или о чем вы?

Comment: Очевидно, что innerHeigh - тоже его высота, причём более полезная, чем outerHeight.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это субъективно, вы конечно можете все что угодно назвать "окном", но это часть экрана, которое занимает приложение и outerHeight возвращает его высоту... если имелось ввиду что-то другое, нужно было и формулировать подругому ))

Comment: Окном обычно называют ту часть окна, которая доступна для веб-страницы - и это как раз innerHeight. А вот зачем мне может понадобиться размер окна вместе с адресной строкой, закладками и devtools, мне пока представить сложно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Обычно окном называют именно окно )) а не веб-страницу, не вижу смысла спорить. По поводу полезности (или бесполезности) атрибутов спор еще менее продуктивный. Все зависит от задачи, если у вас нет задачи использовать какой-то атрибут, то он не становится автоматически бесполезен ))

Comment: @Qwertiy, Простой пример - автотестинг сайтов, иногда очень нужны положение окна, его размеры и абсолютные координаты элементов относительно рабочего стола.